# Accessing multiple drives from IPython notebook server

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have IPython notebooks on both my C: drive and H: drive. At present, if I want to open notebooks from both drives simultaneously I have to run two IPython Notebook servers (one on each drive).

Is it possible to access notebooks on a different drive to the drive where the IPython Notebook server is running?

Ideally, I'd like to start the server on my C: and then navigate to notebooks on any drives.